# Avoid OK Retry button for Xamarin Camera

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using the Camera code base from 
    https://github.com/rasmuschristensen/XamarinFormsImageGallery
to open camera, take picture and show in the gallery. In the droid project, after taking the picture, the dialog asks either to keep the photo or discard it using OK and Retry button. Is there anyway, I can avoid this step and go to next step.

Regards

Comment: this code uses the Xamarin Media plugin to take photos.  You could modify the source of that library to remove that dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Media plugin you won't be able to do it. This plugin use the standard way of capturing photos in Android which rely on the device actual camera app. The save/retry functionality is part of the Camera App and we don't have access to it as  this will be different between Android "providers" (Samsung, LG, Sony, etc)

One way to avoid this is capturing the photo within your own app using the SurfaceView and not using the camera app. I found [this](https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment) example but unfortunately is written in Java but I think it's not too hard to translate into Xamarin/C#.

Comment: yes, i was thinking same. thanks a lot for your answer.