# How to don't open page select "Retry" or "OK" when take photo use library Plugin.Media on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, plugin.media.crossmedia

When I take Photo that save image, It will display sub layout choose "Retry" or "OK" for image. I don't want display it.

I use library Plugin.Media on Xamarin Forms and my code:

Handler event click button capture:

```
    private void CaptureImageCommandHandler()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await CheckPermissionCamera();

                if (Images == null)
                    Images = new ObservableCollection<string>();

                // Create a temp image. It'll be detelted after upload this temp image
                var path = await MediaManagement.TakePhoto();
                if (path == null)
                    return;

                // Add image
                AddImage(path, Localization.Resource.Photo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Exception(ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

Code of method `TakePhoto()`:

```
    public async Task<string> TakePhoto(float? width = null, float? height = null)
    {
        try
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
            var mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions());
            if (mediaFile?.Path == null)
                return null;

            // This is: Taking a photo action
            var result = await ResizeImageFile(mediaFile.Path, width, height, true).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is image of page.

[image: Image Page]

Please help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44092826/4251242), you can't do it using Plugin.Media.

> This plugin use the standard way of capturing photos in Android which rely on the device actual camera app. The save/retry functionality is part of the Camera App and we don't have access to it as this will be different between Android "providers".

That means you need to find a way around this issue. But also there is a link in this answer, that could help you. Hope it helps!

Comment: On iOS, page "OK" or "Retry" is display, too. How to don't open it?